# Pattern for matching letters and digits in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I can't find any pattern for matching letters and numbers in sql query.

`[PG]\d+.*` - This is the pattern for the query
I've tried some things but i only match letter or digit not both.

```
 SELECT * FROM cars WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^[PG]\d');
```

It must match everything that starts with p or g followed by digits and ends with some letters.
Something like this `p01929ki, g9102rt`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using MySQL. But i think there's no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider a pattern like

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^[pg][0-9]+[[:alpha:]]*$')
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0LVw3/1).

**Details**

- `^`  - string start
- `[pg]` - `p` or `g`
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `[[:alpha:]]*` - 0+ letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 select * from cars where regexp_like(model,'^[pg][0-9]+[[a-zA-z]+$')
```

Comment: I have find solution. Thank you very much.